# Xamarin.forms how I can add ability to take photo or select it from Gallery

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am Using **Xamarin.Forms**, how I can add ability to take photo or select it from Gallery.
I Find a lot of solutions, but no one of them is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Xamarin Forms [Media plugin](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/mediaplugin) will do this, and includes sample code

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
        {

          if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.PhotosSupported)
          {
            DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
          }

          var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Media.Plugin.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {

              Directory = "Sample",
              Name = "test.jpg"
            });

          if (file == null)
            return;

          DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

          image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
          {
            var stream = file.GetStream();
            file.Dispose();
            return stream;
          }); 
        };
```

Comment: Thanks , I am beginner with xamarin.forms could you please tell me how to add Media plugin to my project (could you please give me all steps )

Comment: for Forms projects, use nuget to add the package to both the shared project and each platform project

Comment: visual studio not responding when i am trying to search about nuget , what i should do after i add it

Comment: i try Install-Package Xam.Plugin.Media and it is works fine with me

Comment: right now i get 'IMedia' does not contain a definition for 'PhotosSupported' and no extension method 'PhotosSupported' accepting a first argument of type 'IMedia' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: 'Task<MediaFile>' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' and no extension method 'Dispose' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: have you tried looking at the sample apps that use the Media plugin?

Comment: yes and everything working fine ..thanks alot...could you please vote my question  up

Answer (score 0):

This can now be easily achieved using Xamarin Essentials MediaPicker.

Here is the link to the docs and sample code for Android, iOS and UWP..

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android

Answer (score -1):

```
        var profile = new Image { };
        profile.Source = "profile.png";
        profile.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
        profile.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;

        var profiletap = new TapGestureRecognizer();

        profiletap.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
        {
           var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
            if (file == null)
                return;
              await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            im = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
               var stream = file.GetStream();
                //file.Dispose();
                return stream;

            });

            profile.Source = im;


    //   await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PhotoPage(im));
        };

        profile.GestureRecognizers.Add(profiletap);
```